# Ruby .times method called on an integer. How does it know to iterate through each integer as the argument in a block?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading the ["Pickaxe" ruby book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974514055) and I came across this example:

```
def meth_three
  100.times do |num|
    square = num*num
    return num, square if square > 1000
  end
end
```

If you call `meth_three` in irb it returns the first integer between 1 and 100 that has a `square > 1000`:

```
meth_three # => [32, 1024]
```

My question is, how does the `times` method know how to loop through each integer between 1..100 to pass as the argument to the `|num|` parameter?

Comment: It doesn't "know", it was simply programmed that way. Can you be a little bit more specific about what, specifically is unclear to you?

Comment: [This is how it knows](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/802bcd3ec81c1f5de77dbfbe8d9934c5760c85d7/numeric.c#L5171-L5194).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `times` method actually returns a value, which is the current iterator with every loop it makes  *(1, 2, 3 ... 100)*.
The `do`  keyword catches this iterator, and uses it as the variable `num`.
Anytime you see the `num` variable, you are seeing the current iterator that's being returned by `times`.

Comment: Thank you @Viktor, I've changed my answer to reflect your feedback :)

Answer (score 4):

There are many, many different ways of writing iteration in Ruby.

Here is one possible way that it could be implemented recursively:

```rb
class Integer
  def times(&blk)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    return self unless positive?

    pred.times(&blk)

    yield pred
  end
end
```

Or, using `Range#each`:

```rb
class Integer
  def times(&blk)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    return self unless positive?

    (0...self).each(&blk)

    self
  end
end
```

Or, with a loop:

```rb
class Integer
  def times
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    return self unless positive?

    i = -1
    yield i while (i += 1) < self

    self
  end
end
```

And a tail-recursive implementation just for the fun of it:

```rb
class Integer
  def times(&blk)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?
    return self unless positive?

    __times_rec(0, &blk)

    self
  end

  private def __times_rec(i, &blk)
    return unless i < self

    yield i

    __times_rec(i.succ, &blk)
  end
end
```

Here is the *actual* code from an *actual* Ruby implementation ([`core/integer.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/integer.rb#L1379-L1388) from [Rubinius](http://rubinius.com/)):

> ```rb
> def times
>  return to_enum(:times) { self } unless block_given?
>
>  i = 0
>    while i < self
>      yield i
>      i += 1
>    end
>  self
> end
> ```

[TruffleRuby](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/) uses the exact same code as well (see [`src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/integer.rb`](https://github.com/oracle/truffleruby/blob/master/src/main/ruby/truffleruby/core/integer.rb#L135-L144)), as does [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) (see [`core/src/main/ruby/jruby/ruby_implementations/Integer/times.rb`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/ruby/jruby/ruby_implementations/Integer/times.rb#L2-L8))

Here is another real example from a real Ruby implementation ([`opal/corelib/number.rb`](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/opal/corelib/number.rb#L851-L861) from [Opal](http://opalrb.com/)):

> ```rb
> def times(&block)
>  return enum_for(:times) { self } unless block
>
>  %x{
>    for (var i = 0; i < self; i++) {
>      block(i);
>    }
>  }
>
>  self
> end
> ```

As you can see, there are many ways in which one could write a loop in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the comments hint at what is going on. I think it can be explained like this:

Each integer in Ruby is actually an object, more specifically an instance of the `Integer` class.

You can think of it as a `Integer#times` method, that could naively be implemented something like this:

```
class Integer
  def times(&block)
    if self.value > 0
      for i in 0...self.value do
        block.call(i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This method is actually implemented in C in the official version of ruby (MRI), as pointed out in one of the comments to your question. I only write something similar here to help explain the concept on how it could have looked in Ruby.

Comment: "This method is actually implemented in C in order to be more performant" – That is not true at all. In Rubinius, TruffleRuby, and JRuby, it is implemented in Ruby. In JRuby and and TruffleRuby, it *used* to be implemented in Java, but they replaced it with the Ruby version from Rubinius, precisely because it is *more* performant when it is in Ruby. In Opal, it is implemented in Ruby with inline ECMAScript. In IronRuby, it is implemented in C#. I haven't looked at MagLev in a long time, but I am pretty sure it was implemented in either Ruby or Smalltalk there. In MacRuby, it was Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you so much for this piece of information! I had no idea. It is still implemented in C in MRI though. I guess I only assumed that performance was the reason.

Comment: Rbinius, TruffleRuby, and JRuby have heavily optimizing compilers. But of course, a *Ruby* compiler can only optimize *Ruby* code, it cannot optimize Java or C. That's why rewriting stuff in Ruby can actually be faster. Especially since the optimizer can inline the calls inside the block into the `times` method and then inline the `times` method into the caller, which also only works if all methods are in the same language.

Comment: Yes, of course! That does make sense. I removed the art about `times` being implemented in C _due to performance reasons_, and made it more clear that the MRI version is still implemented in C, and I take it that most people learning Ruby will probably be using MRI.

Again, thank you for pointing this out :)

Comment: "I take it that most people learning Ruby will probably be using MRI." – Unfortunately :-D The fact that you can dive deep into Rubinius, and *almost everything* you encounter is still Ruby would be such an awesome learning experience. Wonder how a method works? Just read it, and you don't even have to learn a new language.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I guess that's the case. I never got around to work a lot with any of the other Ruby implementations, and nowadays I'm mostly in Python and Elixir land.